# Kubernetes - is a container's volumeMounts.mountPath relative to the PersistentVolume's hostPath?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

Let's say I create a PersistentVolume of type hostPath:

```yaml
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mypv
spec:
  storageClassName: normal
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: /etc/foo  # Path on the host machine
```

and I create the corresponding PersistentVolumeClaim, and use it in a Pod:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: busybox
  name: busybox
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    name: busybox
    volumeMounts:
    - name: myvolume
      mountPath: /var/log # is this relative to the hostPath of the PV?
  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
  - name: myvolume
    persistentVolumeClaim
      claimName: mypvc
status: {}
```

Is it expected that the result would be `{hostPath}/{mountPath}` (e.g. `/etc/foo/var/log`), or would I have to specifically define `mountPath: /etc/foo/var/log` to get it there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `mountPath` is the mountpoint inside the container. It is an absolute path starting at the *container's* filesystem root. If `mountPath` is `/var/log`, then the volume will be mounted on `/var/log` inside the container.

If you have a `hostPath` volume pointing at `/etc/foo` on the host and `mountPath` pointing at `/var/log` in the container, then you will find the contents of `/etc/foo` available inside `/var/log` inside the container.

For more details, see [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/).